# Default file to the Home directory

Tags: haskell, cabal

How do I create a file with my defaults, maybe to the home directory, after installing my cabal package? I save my default file in the source directory. I mean, is any way to say to cabal that after finish or in the beginning, to create that file. Because I would like to have it, later on, when I execute my application.

Comment: The question is not very clear. My understanding is: you are writing an application, using cabal. Said application has a config file, and you would like that, when cabal installs the application, it also installs the config file for it somewhere, so that the user can modify it.

Comment: Yes, This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cabal supports the notion of data files which will be installed with your application, and it also provides an API you can use to determine where the data files actually reside.

In your cabal file add a `data-files` stanza, e.g.:

```
data-files: file1.txt, img2.jpg
```

The paths are relative to your project directory.

Then in your application use this code:

```
import Paths_project_name
...

foo = do path <- getDataFileName "file1.txt"
         ...
         img <- getDataFileName "img2.jpg"
         ...
```

Here _project_name_ is the name of the cabal project. E.g., if you cabal file is named **Blather.cabal**, then you would import **Paths_Blather**.

More info is available in this blog post:

http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/02/adding-data-files-using-cabal.html